# Insert point into a PostGis enabled Postgres db

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, postgis

I have this (non working) query:

```
"INSERT INTO notes (
         lat, 
         lng, 
         point)
      VALUES (
         :lat,
         :lng,
         ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(:lat :lng)'))"
```

Which I am running against this table:

```
CREATE TABLE notes
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  lat real NOT NULL,
  lng real NOT NULL,
  point point NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT notes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

The query is prepared with PDO (php) but that is not the point I think. The result I get back is an exception claiming that:

```
SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "point" is of type point but expression is of type geometry
LINE 8:          $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(:...
                                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How can I cast the expression as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the standard Postgres type [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6545):

```
"INSERT INTO notes (lat, lng, point)
 VALUES (:lat, :lng, '(:lat, :lng)'::point)"
```

You may want to use the PostGis type [`geometry`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/geometry.html) in your table instead.

Comment: Oh so when I do `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` new data types are added?

Comment: @nourdine: Yes. Lots of new types and functions and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to use PostgreSQL's `point` type, or PostGIS's `geometry` type. If it is the later, [this answer should help out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24487/1872).